# Mapping PolarSSL x509_cert structure to PKCS#11 X.509 object

Tags: c++, mapping, x509certificate, pkcs#11, polarssl

I want to write a C++ program to parse a X.509 compatible certificate file with PolarSSL, extract all of it's attributes & map them to a PKCS#11 object template for storing on a cryptographic token. I also need to be able to fetch stored object attributes & re-create original file using them, but I exactly don't know how to map between PolarSSL x509_cert struct fields & PKCS#11 X.509 object attributes.
I know part of this mapping (i.e. `crt.valid_from` maps to `CKA_START_DATE` or `crt.valid_to` maps to `CKA_END_DATE`) & need these attributes for creating my certificate object on the token (all of these values must be set according to PKCS#11 specs):

```
CKA_CERTIFICATE_CATEGORY
CKA_CHECK_VALUE
CKA_SUBJECT
CKA_ID
CKA_ISSUER
CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER
CKA_VALUE
CKA_URL
CKA_HASH_OF_SUBJECT_PUBLIC_KEY
CKA_HASH_OF_ISSUER_PUBLIC_KEY
CKA_JAVA_MIDP_SECURITY_DOMAIN
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to understand two specs: [X509 (RFC 5280)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) and [PKCS#11](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf). A certificate is a cryptographically "whole" object, whereas the many optional "helper attributes" in PKCS#11 have no cryptographic value. For example, I believe that CKA_JAVA_MIDP_SECURITY_DOMAIN is something that makes close to zero point in *real life* in 2013. If you take a certificate as a blob, you only need to care about the raw certificate data (AKA CKA_VALUE) and the subject of the certificate (CKA_SUBJECT). Unless you explain why you want "all the attributes" my guess is you want to do something you should not actually do.